# "should at least be" or "should be...,at least" or "at least, should be" , which one is grammatically correct?

Tags: sentence-choice, sentence-usage

Which of the following sentence would be correct, please explain and also tell about cases where each of the correct sentences can be used:

> - The number of employees ***should at least be*** 1.
> - The number of employees ***should be*** 1, ***at least***.
> - The number of employees, ***at least, should be*** 1.

I personally think the 2nd sentence is wrong and 1st and 3rd options are correct.

Comment: "...should be at least one" seems the most idiomatic to me. The others are understandable, but don't sound at all natural.

Answer (score -2):

The correct way to use the phrase is should be, at least because if you discover something that doesn't add up you would say " there should be, at least" followed by the value amount of emphasis partaining to amount.